# Deploy приложения на Wildfly через Wildfly maven plugin с HTTPS

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

Настроил админку на сервере Wildfly через https, по умолчанию был http.  Админка работает, но перестал работать maven plugin для Wildfly, падает с ошибкой:

> Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9993. The connection
>   failed: XNIO000816: Redirect encountered establishing connection

Настройка такая:

```
    <wildfly.hostname>localhost</wildfly.hostname> 
    <wildfly.port>9993</wildfly.port>
```

В doc-е по плагину ничего нужного не нашел.

Заранее спасибо за любые направления.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, тайна крылась в классе исходников:

```
org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionConfiguration и методе: setUri
```

а именно, в конфигурировании нужно использовать тэг:

```
<protocol></protocol>
```

который описан в доке, но вот его значение не очевидно и может быть таким:

```
remote+http  
http-remoting  
remote+https  
https-remoting
```

в моем случае понадобилось:

```
remote+https
```